# Display the flag link only for the node author

Tags: views, flags

I'm trying to display the flag link only for the node author, and I'm using the following code:

```
global $user;
if ($node->uid == $user->uid) {
  //print your flag
}
```

The link doesn't appear.

Do you have any idea on what is causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Please provide additional information.  Without seeing the function it is in and its context to your custom module, it is hard provide any answers.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [hook_flag_access()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21flag%21flag.api.php/function/hook_flag_access/7), as in the following code.

```
 function crystal_qa_flag_access($flag, $entity_id, $action, $account) {
   // Only the author of the question has right to use flag "Accepeted" on answers.
   if (($flag->name == 'accepted') && ($flag->content_type == 'node')  && ($node = node_load($entity_id))) {
     if ($node->type=='answer') {
       // The content type machine name must be answer.
       $question_nid = $node->field_answer['und']['0']['target_id'];
       $question = node_load($question_nid);
       return ($question->uid == $account->uid);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This seems the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by declaring `$user` to be a blank variable right before you use it, you're overwriting Drupal's variable?

Comment: The variable is not set to a blank variable, when using `global $user`.